# Electromagnetism Basics

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

[image]

Above is the problem and my attempt to solve it. I am not able to get any of the options and I also doubt my approach as unit vector(pho) and unit vector(phi) will be changing continuously throughout the curve.

Please help me with the problem and I will really appreciate if you can suggest multiple ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral cumulates the place difference between the endpoint and the startpoint. The total transition vector is the X unit vector multiplied by -2 times the radius of the circle. The problem does not search a formal calculation but the most basic understanding of the vector integration along a path.

Your formal calculation which splits the integral to three parts is not ok as you suspected, because the unit vectors are not constant. You must express the unit vectors as rotated X and Y unit vectors. Those are constant, only sin and cos terms must be left inside the integrals.

The mid part from (0,1) to (0,-1) does not need rotation.

Comment: I was able to get the answer both ways. Thanks @user287001